# Sphinx query column attribute problem?

Tags: php, sphinx

```
source tags
{
    type                            = mysql
    sql_host                        = localhost
    sql_user                        = abc
    sql_pass                        = 123456
    sql_db                          = company
    sql_sock                        =  /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
    sql_port                        = 3306

     sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
     sql_query_range        = SELECT 1,max(id) FROM companies

sql_query                       = \
        SELECT a1,a2,a3,a4.....................,a64 FROM companies;
;

}
```

IN my query more 32 columns is there .
in my linux server i am getting error more then 32 columns not available.
How can i extend this columns size.

Comment: What type of data is in your attribute columns? int, string, bool, etc?

Comment: 5 columns int,5 bool,5 double,5 float,44 string.

Comment: sorry, I'm unsure how you can get those 44 string attributes in there. Would suggest posting over in the forum on sphinxsearch.com

Comment: i think you need to better normalize your data

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can concatenate some of your text data so it's presented as single column to sphinx?

change

```
SELECT a1,a2,a3,a4.....................,a64 FROM companies
```

into

```
SELECT concat(a1,a2,a3,a17,a62,a63,a64),a4..........a60 FROM companies
```